OLD P3D model files for old games
We are currently modding an old game but having trouble finding out how to create a model in old P3D, then insert it into the game. In addition, we'd like to export some of the existing models so we can have a reference point.
I know Arma 3 uses P3D, but they use proprietary software to achieve that.
Where can I find a tool or guide or script/plugin/addon to achieve these goals?

in Blender it looks like there's an addon to import/export p3d? https://github.com/wurunduk/blender-p3d-import-export

Ya i tried that and it is only for crashday models. I really appreciaate you directing me there. Any other ideas?
